# Gaussian with exponential variance from Cinlar's book.

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

I am reading Cinlar's Book about Probability and Stochastic in example 1.16 page 55.
I met an integral as follows $$\int_0^{\infty} c \exp(-cx)\frac{\exp(-\frac{y^2}{2x})}{\sqrt{2\pi x}} dx = \frac{1}{2}b \exp(-b|y|), \qquad b = \sqrt{2c}.$$
Can someone help me how to get the result of this integral. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^{\infty} c \exp(-cx)\frac{\exp(-\frac{y^2}{2x})}{\sqrt{2\pi x}} dx = 2 c \int_0^{\infty} \exp(-cz^2)\frac{\exp(-\frac{y^2}{2z^2})}{\sqrt{2\pi}} dz$$
Here I use substitution $x=z^2$.

Let us consider the integral
$$
I(a,b)= \int_0^{\infty} dz \exp(-a z^2-\frac{b}{z^2})
$$
for arbitrary parameters $a$ and $b$. Do substitution $z=z(\dfrac{b}{a})^{1/4}$ we obtain
$$
I(a,b)=(\dfrac{b}{a})^{1/4} e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}\int_0^{\infty} dz \exp(-\sqrt{a b}(z-1/z)^2 )=
(\dfrac{b}{a})^{1/4}e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dz}{z^2} \exp(-\sqrt{a b}(z-1/z)^2 )
$$
In the last expression I did substiotution $z=1/z$.To sum thes two substitution and dividing them by two we obtain:
$$
I(a,b)=\frac{1}{2}(\dfrac{b}{a})^{1/4}e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}\int_0^{\infty}  \exp(-\sqrt{a b}(z-1/z)^2 ) d(z-1/z)=\frac{1}{2}(\dfrac{b}{a})^{1/4}e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \exp(-\sqrt{a b}t^2 ) dt=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{-2\sqrt{ab}}\
$$, where $t=z-1/z$
If you put the correct expressions for the parameters $a$ and $b$, you will get the desired result.